# tikz: get rectangle borders to overlap rather than touch

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I want some rectangles that are adjacent to each other in a line. Almost got it, but the rectangles have borders which touch, and I want the borders to overlap. Is there a way to do this?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%
%%%>
\title{boxes1}
\tikzset{
  >=latex,
  font=\sffamily
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\coordinate (pen) at (0,0);
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1}
{
  \node[rectangle, thin, draw, anchor=west, minimum width=\x*3 cm](rnode)at (pen) {\xi} ;
  \coordinate (pen) at (rnode.east);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: looks like a duplicate.

Comment: your MWE can be simplified to: `\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,chains,positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
         font = \sffamily,
node distance = 0pt,
  start chain = going right,
 boxes/.style = {draw, thin, outer sep=0pt, on chain}
                        ]
\foreach \x [count = \xi] in {0.1,0.2,0.1,0.1}
{\node[boxes,minimum width=\x*3 cm] {\xi};}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`, which also solve your problem.